# setsockopt() with RCVTIMEO is not working in windows mobile5

Tags: sockets, tcp, windows-mobile

I am trying to timeout the recieve() call on the socket descriptor, by using setsockopt() API with so_rcvtimeo option set with time set to 5 seconds. but my recieve() call is not timing out after 5 seconds when data is not recieved from server.

may i know if there is any settings to be enabled in windows mobile 5 to get this working or is there any other way to achieve this in windows mobile 5 / pocket pc

Thanks and regards

Comment: ?If the socket is created using the WSASocket function, then the dwFlags parameter must have the WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED attribute set for the timeout to function properly. Otherwise the timeout never takes effect.

Comment: Also, see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesnative/thread/65f6c563-07fa-4e36-8b71-438a15b942a9/

Comment: Eric,socket is created using normal socket() function

Comment: the discussion forums specified by you indicates that rcvtimeout is not implemented in windows mobile 5

Answer (score 0):

The [MSDN documentation for `setsocketopt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa926453.aspx) clearly states (in the Remarks section):

> The following list shows BSD options that are not supported for **setsockopt**.
>
> SO_ACCEPTCONN
> SO_RCVLOWAT
> SO_RCVTIMEO  **<--- Note this one**
> SO_SNDLOWAT
> SO_SNDTIMEO
> SO_TYPE

The "workaround" is to do the receive on a separate thread and wait on that thread in the caller, with a timeout that aborts the spawned thread.

Comment: But is there any way to achieve this recieve time out without multi threaded programming ?? i got sequential processing of the calls

Comment: Not without multi-threading, no.  You can still fake synchronous behavior by having the thread signal an event that the caller waits on.