# Port setsockopt() with RCVTIMEO for Windows CE

Tags: c, sockets, windows-ce, winsock2

I am porting a socket based application from Linux to Windows CE 6.0. I came across a line of code which was setting the socket option for Receive Timeout.

`struct timeval timeout = 200;
timeout.tv_usec = 200000;
setsockopt(mySock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&timeout, (socklen_t) sizeof(timeout));`

I searched for possible porting implementations and could find these two threads relevant.
[setsockopt() with RCVTIMEO is not working in windows mobile5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050594/setsockopt-with-rcvtimeo-is-not-working-in-windows-mobile5) and 
[Set timeout for winsock recvfrom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824465/set-timeout-for-winsock-recvfrom)

After setting the receive timeout as 200ms, there is a call to recv() for receiving data from the remote IP(sender).
The first link explained clearly to spawn off a thread and wait on it but 200ms looked too less for my case as the sender sends for ~10 sec.
The second link's select() suggestion is what I added to my code but the behavior is very inconsistent. Sometimes it receives no packets, sometimes 1 or sometimes more. But the existing implementation works fine on Linux.

Am I doing the porting right way? Can anyone point out a probable mistake or make a suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered adding some error-checking? e.g. to the `setsockopt()` call?

Answer (score 0):

I think the "select()" suggestion to port your linux code is the right one.

I would use the following code:

```
struct timeval tmout;

#ifdef LINUX
//...
#else
while (true)
{

           struct fd_set fds;
           // Set up the file descriptor set.
           FD_ZERO(&fds) ;
           FD_SET(mySock, &fds) ;

           // Set up the struct timeval for the timeout.
           tmout.tv_sec = 0 ;
           tmout.tv_usec = 200000 ;

           // Wait until timeout or data received.

           n = select ( NULL, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tmout ) ;

           if ( n == 0)
           { 
             printf("select() Timeout..\n");
             //return 0 ;
           }
           else if( n == SOCKET_ERROR )
           {
             printf("select() Error!! %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
             //return 1;   
           }
           else
               printf("select() returns %d\n", n);
}
#endif
```

I'm running the same code in a WCE6 app and it is working fine for me.
If you are executing this code in a loop and your sender is sending every 10 seconds you should see every 10 seconds the select returning n>0.

Hope this is helpful